# Do any of the latest browsers offer a modal confirm Yes No Dialog box?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have been used to hand coding this type of thing in the past. With all the new things coming out with CSS3 has anyone seen any browsers yet supporting something like an alert box that will also give the user a couple of buttons for OK and Cancel. Note that I am not talking about a framework alert box. I was asking about something that might be part of Safari or Firefox.

Comment: See here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: `confirm()` has been a standard feature of browsers at least since Netscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

```js
var bro = confirm("Bro, do you even javascript?");

alert("you selected " + bro);
```

It returns a boolean after the user selects his or her choice. It is a blocking function, use wisely :)

Answer (score 1):

[confirm()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) ? is this function what you want?

```
confirm('Some question....'); // displae OK / Cancel btns
```

> The confirm() method displays a dialog box with a specified message,
>   along with an OK and a Cancel button.
>
> A confirm box is often used if you want the user to verify or accept
>   something.
>
> Note: The confirm box takes the focus away from the current window,
>   and forces the browser to read the message. Do not overuse this
>   method, as it prevent the user from accessing other parts of the page
>   until the box is closed.
>
> The confirm() method returns true if the user clicked "OK", and false
>   otherwise.

Example
http://jsbin.com/mabedoqufa/1/edit?html,js,output